# Salesforce Support, Lack of Communication

Tags: support, salesforce-support

I was wondering if there's some sort of place I can report opened tickets. I currently have one in which I haven't heard from my support guy in 2 business weeks (13 days), This ticket has been opened for over 40 days. Is there any way I can report this ticket as being lost? Maybe he left salesforce and my ticket is floating in the void?

In case someone from Salesforce is here my Case Number is 10099809.

Comment: Is your ticket related to something unique to your salesforce org, or a more general salesforce bug (reproducible in a dev org)?

Comment: Its based on a filter lookup issue. IE: SobjectA, SobjectB.
SobjectA is the parent of SobjectB. Lookup filter on SobjectA requires the id to match the lookup of the parent to from SobjectB to SobjectA. This is required as multiple SobjectBs can belong to a single SobjectA record.

Comment: I think the answer is a good one, but you may also want to search for your issue on here and post it as a question if you can't find the answer.

Comment: Alright, let me make a new post and I'll put it here if I can explain it enough

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bring your Account Executive in on the discussion. They want to make sure you are happy, and will follow up with support. If you are on Twitter, you can try and send a message to @Salesforce. Their social media people do a pretty good job of tracking down cases as well.

Comment: Took 4 posts to twitter over 2 days to finally get a response. Rep magically appeared after almost 20 days of silence to tell me it was product limitation and closed my ticket within 10 minutes of salesforce responding to twitter... I really can't stand salesforce's support =(

Comment: Bummer. Did you post your question here? Maybe we can come up with a creative solution.

Comment: Yep, it was this one... [StackExchange Question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28806/salesforce-lookup-filter-issue)