# Salesforce Lookup Filter Issue

Tags: lookup-filter

I'm currently having an issue with Salesforce in which we are currently using the Sobject 'Case' which will be known as Sobject_A and another object called 'Case Concern' which will be known as Sobject_B.

Sobject_B currently has a master detail relationship / lookup to Sobject_A. Thus Sobject_A can have many Sobject_B records.

Now in order to close Sobject_A, we have a lookup field from Sobject_A to Sobject_B with a filter. The filter is Sobject_A.Id must equal Sobject_B.Sobject_A.Id (Sobject_B has a lookup to Sobject_A this was the simplest representation). Now the problem is there are on results being returned. Salesforce has requested for us to test out our scenario by by making a tab for Sobject_B. Now, if we have looked at multiple Sobject_B record that are and are not associated to Sobject_A the recently view seems to filter these results just fine, but it kills the entire point of having a filter and adds unneeded steps to the streamline process. I also cannot keep the tab due to how many tabs one is allowed to have per org. Do any one of you have suggestions on how to resolve this issue? If a better explanation is needed I can draw out the scenario.

Comment: Is your lookup filter on the field from sObject_A to sObject_B marked as Required? If this is the case it shouldn't be possible to select a record that doesn't meet the filter criteria. When the filter is optional users can drop the filter an select other records.

Comment: It is only required when setting a status to closed.

Comment: If the lookup filter isn't marked as required then users can optionally bypass it and make the association to another record. You could use a trigger to enforce more complex relationship constraints and/or a custom visualforce page to only present the correct options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce support after having this ticket opened for 50+ days...

> I've tried everything and still not be able to achieve what were trying to do with the lookup filter. All of the related issue with lookup filter was tagged as product limitation.
>
> Thank you for choosing Salesforce and have great day!

So a Parent Object and not use it's own Id to make sure the related lookup object has the matching parent Id.